# Not able to create bean of java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor using Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to create a bean of `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`, below is what I have in my spring config file:

```
<bean id="threadPoolExector" class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor" lazy-init="true" scope="singleton">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="${corePoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${maximumPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="keepAliveTime" value="${keepAliveTime}"/>
    <property name="unit" value="java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS"/>
    <property name="workQueue" ref="abcBlockingQueueImpl"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="abcBlockingQueueImpl" class="my.package.AbcBlockingQueueImpl" lazy-init="true" scope="singleton"/>
```

Then I am trying to create as below:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) applicationContext.getBean("threadPoolExector");
```

But I get below exception, I know there is no no-arg for `ThreadPoolExecutor` but I am surprised that I am getting this exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadPoolExector' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/web-applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.&lt;init>()
```

I have used Spring beans before but this looks like a weird problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the end:

```
... No default constructor found; ...
```

ThreadPoolExecutor does not have a default constructor, you'd have to simulate what you described in the code: setting constructor arguments for at least the smallest constructor using `<constructor-arg>` tags instead of `<property>` tags:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)
```

In the context XML file:

```
<bean id="threadPoolExector" class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor" lazy-init="true" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="int" value="${corePoolSize}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="${maximumPoolSize}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" type="long" value="${keepAliveTime}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="3" type="java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit" value="java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS"/>
    <constructor-arg index="4"  ref="abcBlockingQueueImpl"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Yes, I did got that but even if I extend `ThreadPoolExecutor` I would still get same problem, and I do not want to create a instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` manually or have `ThreadPoolExecutor` as instance of a class. Can something be done, I am not getting any way out except 2 thing I mentioned above which I do not want to do.

Comment: @hagrawal no need to extend anything. Just set the properties with constructor-args, just as you would do in Java code. (edited answer to show it)

Comment: Ok, give 20 minutes, I will be back and try.

Comment: Thanks mate, got it.